# django Sitemap class alternates not rendering sitemap.xml

Tags: python-3.x, django, sitemap, xml-sitemap, alternate

I have a problem with adding alternates attribute to my sitemaps.py

sitemaps.py

```
class StaticViewSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'weekly' 
    protocol = 'https' 
    i18n = True 
    alternates = True

def alternate_hreflangs(self, obj):
    return [('en-us', obj.alternative_object_url), ]

def items(self):
    return ['index','about', 'contact', 'why', 'product', 'tender-management', 'e-sourcing', 'network', 'faq']

def location(self, item):
    return reverse(item)
```

when I set the `alternates = True` my sitemap.xml file broke and show a string file

```
https://example.com/en/weekly0.5https://example.com/en/about/weekly0.5https://example.com/en/contact/weekly0.5
```

Instead of

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<url>
<loc>https://example.com/en/</loc>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://example.com/en/about/</loc>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://example.com/en/contact/</loc>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

I get this problem only when adding the `alternates = True` my sitemap.xml

Comment: Did you try https://pypi.org/project/django-qartez/?

Comment: No, I'd like to use the offical alternates attribute from django